# Understanding scala.collection.immutable.ListSet implementation

Tags: scala, collections, set

I'm looking at how `scala.collection.immutable.ListSet[T]` at 2.12 is implemented and have a question about how it works:

```
sealed class ListSet[A] extends AbstractSet[A]
  with Set[A]
  with GenericSetTemplate[A, ListSet]
  with SetLike[A, ListSet[A]]
  with Serializable {

  def +(elem: A): ListSet[A] = new Node(elem)

  //...

  protected class Node(override protected val elem: A) extends ListSet[A] with Serializable {
      override def +(e: A): ListSet[A] = if (contains(e)) this else new Node(e)
     //...
  }
}
```

As can be seen the `Node.+(e: A)` simply creates a new Node with the given element. How is the reference to the `Node` on which the `+` was invoked is retained? The `next` method is implemented as

```
override protected def next: ListSet[A] = ListSet.this
```

which should give us the reference to the initial empty `ListSet` instance.

Can you please explain how this works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Node` is defined as an inner class of `ListSet` each instance of `Node` automatically contains a reference to the instance of the outer class it was created in.

You can access this instance of the outer `ListSet` from within the inner class with the expression `ListSet.this`

Comment: This is the main difference between "proper" nested classes as invented in Beta and implemented in gBeta, Scala, Newspeak, etc. and the "crippled" nested classes in Java and friends. In "proper" nested classes, a copy of the nested class is nested inside *each instance* of the outer class. In Java, nested classes are nested inside the *class*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I tried a simple example myself and noticed that it works if the `Node` is declared as `protected`, but does not work if the `Node` is declared `private`. Why is that?